# Rethrow exceptions from Lamdba

Tags: java, lambda

I have this code:

```
public static void processConditions(@NotNull List<EntityCondition> conditions)
      throws UnsatisfiedConditionException {
    conditions.forEach(
       consumerWrapper(
           entityCondition -> {
              throw new UnsatisfiedConditionException(entityCondition);
           }, UnsatisfiedConditionException.class));
}
```

Which throws an exception and having this *consumer*:

```
public interface ThrowingConsumer<T> {
  void accept(T t) throws Exception;
}
```

And wrapper:

```
public static <T, E extends Exception> Consumer<T> consumerWrapper(
      ThrowingConsumer<T> consumer, Class<E> clazz) {
    return i -> {
      try {
        consumer.accept(i);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        try {
          E exCast = clazz.cast(ex);
          System.err.println(
              "Exception occurred : " + exCast.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassCastException ccEx) {
          //throw ex;
        }
      }
    };
  }
```

With this `consumerWrapper` can swallow the exceptions thrown by the lambda, however I need it to "rethrow" it, thus `throw ex;` As such the method `processConditions` here can throw it.

How can that be achieved?

Comment: You simply can't do that if you stick to `Consumer<T>` for your lambda expression. What's the point of `ThrowingConsumer<T>` if you have to produce a `Consumer<T>` in the end?

Comment: @ernest_k I can definitely see the point of `ThrowingConsumer<T>`. It allows you to pass a method that `throws` as a lambda. The `consumerWrapper` method then converts this to a regular `Consumer` that _doesn't_ throw a particular type of exception.

Comment: @Sweeper Exactly, but the OP is again intending to throw the "swallowed" checked exception... which raises the question of why want to produce `Consumer` at all (instead of just sticking with `ThrowingConsumer`)

Comment: @ernest_k Because `forEach` (the method that OP is ultimately trying to call) doesn't accept `ThrowingConsumer`? It's probably that if the `throw ex;` line is reached then something has gone very wrong and the program should stop immediately. It seems like the exception type that the throwing consumer throws should match the `clazz` parameter. And if another type of exception is thrown, it is an unexpected situation. Maybe I'm reading too much into this? :-)

Comment: No, @Sweeper, you're actually having the best picture of it. I'm just whining about the intention of throwing the checked exception again (well, of course the solution in your answer below is what needs to be done; but I just wanted to question the OP's initial intent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to make it work:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingConsumer<T> extends Consumer<T>{
  @Override
  default void accept(final T e) {
    try {
      accept0(e);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
      Throwing.sneakyThrow(ex);
    }
  }
  void accept0(T t) throws Throwable;
}

public final class Throwing {

  private Throwing() {}

  @Nonnull
  public static <T> Consumer<T> rethrow(@Nonnull final ThrowingConsumer<T> consumer) {
    return consumer;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Nonnull
  public static <E extends Throwable> void sneakyThrow(@Nonnull Throwable ex) throws E {
    throw (E) ex;
  }

}
```

And use it like this:

```java
public static void processConditions(@NotNull List<EntityCondition> conditions)
      throws UnsatisfiedConditionException {
    conditions.forEach(
       rethrow(
           entityCondition -> {
              throw new UnsatisfiedConditionException(entityCondition);
           }, UnsatisfiedConditionException.class));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why throwing `ex` doesn't work is because you can't throw checked exceptions in regular `Consumer`s, and `ex` could be a checked exception.

A simple workaround would be to throw an unchecked `RuntimeException`, *with the cause being* `ex`:

```
throw new RuntimeException(ex);
```

Note that this will create a slightly different error message from just throwing `ex`. It will say "`java.lang.RuntimeException`" followed by the stack trace of the `RuntimeException`, followed by "Caused by `WhateverExceptionExIs` ..." followed by the stack trace of `WhateverExceptionExIs`.

You can make your `consumerWrapper` a bit safer by introducing another type parameter to `ThrowingConsumer`:

```
interface ThrowingConsumer<T, E extends Throwable> {
    void accept(T t) throws E;
}

...

public static <T, E extends Exception> Consumer<T> consumerWrapper(
            ThrowingConsumer<T, E> consumer, Class<E> clazz) {
```

So that silly calls like this can be detected at compile time:

```
consumerWrapper(Foo::thisThrowsExceptionFoo, ExceptionBar.class);
```